# Latexmk can't see a dependency on a .fmt format file

Tags: compiling, automation, latexmk, format-files

I'm using latex on a small netbook, and with average-sized files (~150 pages at the moment) compilation is already pretty slow. So I am looking for every way to speed up the compilation.

In this search, I found [this page](http://magic.aladdin.cs.cmu.edu/2007/11/02/precompiled-preamble-for-latex/) explaining how to "precompile a preamble", or, latexically-speaking, how to make a custom format file.
That works fine enough.

But my preamble isn't as static as it should be, I keep adding or modifying definitions in there.
To mix the two solutions, at the moment, I use a Makefile together with `latexmk`, the makefile handling the regeneration of the `.fmt` file if needed, and `latexmk` taking good care of the rest.

But I have two problems with this :

- integration with `emacs` to compile the whole document when working on a single file (`make` needs to be called in the proper directory)
- `latexmk` doesn't recompile the file every time the preamble is modified, because it doesn't count as a dependency.

So I'd like to find a way to get rid of this Makefile, and get all the stuff done by `latexmk`.

I edited my `.latexmkrc` to include this :

```perl
pdflatex = 'pdflatex -fmt main %O %S';

add_input_ext('pdflatex','fmt');

add_cus_dep('tex', 'fmt', 1, 'compilepreamble');
sub compilepreamble {
    print "Preamble compiling...\n";
    $command = '&.pdflatex ./fmt/preamble.tex\dump';
    system("pdflatex -ini -jobname='$_[0]' '$command'");
};
```

But with this, if the file `main.fmt` is not present or if `fmt/preamble.tex` is updated, the `main.fmt` file won't be regenerated.
Actually, in the first case, I get an error from `pdflatex` saying the it can't find `main.fmt` format file. So I understand `latexmk` doesn't even try to build `main.fmt`, it's probably not a problem in my custom dependency. However, I think I've added everything necessary for this to work.

So... Did I forget something? Is there a way round? Or is it a hopeless quest?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you forgot is that a custom dependency is intended to have input and output files that differ only in their extensions, e.g., to convert `foo.ltx` to `foo.fmt`.  But they don't work to convert, for example, `fmt/preamble.tex` to `main.fmt`.  A second, but less severe, problem is that when pdfLaTeX doesn't find the .`fmt` file, it dies with an error message to the screen, but it doesn't put the error message in the log file (so that `latexmk` doesn't detect that there is a missing file).

If you rename your preamble file to `main.ltx` (not in a subdirectory), then the following initialization code should work:

```perl
$recorder = 1;
$pdflatex = 'pdflatex -fmt main %O %S';
add_input_ext('pdflatex','fmt');
add_cus_dep('ltx', 'fmt', 1, 'compilepreamble');
sub compilepreamble {
    print "Preamble compiling for '$_[0]'...\n";
    my $fls_file = "$_[0].fls";
    my $source = "$_[0].ltx";
    my $fmt_file = "$_[0].fmt";
    my $return = system( "pdflatex", "-interaction=batchmode",
                         "-ini", "-recorder", "-jobname=$_[0]",
                         "&pdflatex $source \\dump" );
    if ($return) { 
        warn "Error in making format file '$fmt_file'\n";
       return $return;
    }
    my %input_files = ();
    my %output_files = ();
    $return = parse_fls( $fls_file, \%input_files, \%output_files );
    if ($return) {
        warn "No fls file '$fls_file' made; I cannot get dependency data\n";
        return 0; 
    }
    # Use latexmk's internal variables and subroutines for setting the
    #   dependency information.
    # Note that when this subroutine is called to implement a custom
    #   dependency, the following variables are set:
    #       $rule  contains the name of the current rule (as in the
    #              fdb_latexmk file)
    #       $PHsource is a pointer to a hash of source file
    #              information for the rule.  The keys of the hash are
    #              the names of the source files of the rule.
    foreach my $file (keys %input_files) {
        rdb_ensure_file( $rule, $file );
    }
    foreach my $file (keys %$PHsource) {
        if ( ! exists $input_files{$file} ) {
            print "   Source file of previous run '$file' ",
                  "IS NO LONGER IN USE\n";
            rdb_remove_files( $rule, $file );
        }
    }
    return 0;
};
```

I've used an extension `.ltx` rather than `.tex` so that you can have a preamble file with the same basename as the main file.

You'll need to run the `pdflatex -ini ...` manually the first time, to create the `.fmt` file.  After that `latexmk` should handle things automatically.

**Edit** (2 April 2012): I improved the code so that it detects dependencies on files used by `pdflatex -ini`.    This uses some of the internal variables and subroutines of `latexmk`.

Comment: Ok thank you, it works! I had to add the `-recorder` option for latexmk to acknowledge `pdflatex` was reading `main.fmt`, and my poor knowledge of perl didn't result in proper string management, but now it works. `:)`

Comment: @John Collins I use your code and split up my preamble in main.ltx and main2.ltx. Now only changes in main.ltx are recognized. Is there a way to fix this other than combining the preambles?

Comment: @John Collins: Is there a way, with the current `latexmk`, to avoid having to call `pdflatex -ini ...` manually? I have tried `add_cus_dep('fmt', 'tex', 1, 'my_noop');` with a dummy function `my_noop`, but this didn't change anything. I would like `latexmk` to call `pdflatex -ini ...` when the `.fmt` file is missing, too.

Comment: @maetra: My new solution will detect changes in all files that are used when `pdflatex -ini` makes the format file.

Comment: @user946850: Modify the command string for running `pdflatex` so that if the format file exists, it runs `pdflatex`, but if the format file doesn't exist it makes a 2 line dummy log file.  The first line of the dummy log file starts "This is ", and the second line has the name of the format file in parentheses.  This will provoke `latexmkrc` into thinking there is a correct log file and that the format file is a source file of the run of `pdflatex`; it will then make the format file.

Comment: @T.Verron: The perl syntax highlighting keyword is `lang-perl`, not `perl-lang` `:)`

Comment: @JohnCollins: Do you mean "Modify the command string for running `latexmk` so that if the format file exists, it runs `latexmk`, ...? I'm afraid I don't quite understand your comment as it is. Also, wouldn't it be possible to implement this logic in Perl, as a part of `latexmkrc`?

Comment: @JohnCollins thanks for the improved code, works great!

Comment: I tried it, but I get the following error: Latexmk: Did not finish processing file 'main.tex':
   File '/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/latex.ltx' does not exist to build '/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/latex.fmt'

Comment: my main.tex just contains \input{main.ltx}
\begin{document}
text
\end{document} and main.ltx is the preamble

Comment: I get the same error as @Julia on the first run, and the thesis builds anyway; I don't get that error later. BTW, `\input{main.ltx}` with these instructions is not needed; I use '^&main' in the first line and then drop the `-fmt main` part.

Comment: As of latexmk 4.63b (from TeXLive 2019), this code is broken. I think the shortest fix is to replace `add_input_ext('pdflatex','fmt');` by `$input_extensions{'pdflatex'}{'fmt'} = 1;`; one can also paste a copy of `add_input_ext` from the old `latexmk`. @JohnCollins maybe this code should be part of your test suite?

Comment: @JohnCollins your answer does not work with recent versions (v4.65, June 2019) of `latexmk`, particularly the `add_input_ext` bit.  Secondly, may I request you to please consider editing your answer to incorporate your hint of avoiding the manual first call to `pdftex -ini`, i.e. how can we accomodate the case of creating the `fmt` file if it doesn't already exist?