# Custom format file: How to automate the generation of the "precompiled preamble" whenever one of the files that are used there are changed

Tags: automation, format-files

I would like to speed up compilation of my LaTeX documents using the [precompiled preamble](http://magic.aladdin.cs.cmu.edu/2007/11/02/precompiled-preamble-for-latex/) approach, and I was wondering whether any of the [Tools for automating document compilation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64/8057) have support for this.

The main idea is:

- split the document into a "static" and a "dynamic" part, `preamble.tex` and `main.tex`
- create a custom format file `main.fmt` from the static part using

  ```
    pdflatex -ini -jobname=main "&pdflatex preamble.tex\dump"
  ```
- compile your document using

  ```
    pdflatex -fmt main main
  ```

As a consequence, only the contents of `main.tex` are processed on "regular" compilation, thus accelerating the build. However, if `preamble.tex` *or any of the files used there* changes, the format file will have to be rebuilt.
I would like to automate this: Rebuild `main.fmt` if and only if necessary. Of course, `main.tex` would also be recompiled if the static part (=the format file) has changed *and/or* if the contents or includes of the dynamic part have changed.

I have tried latexmk and scons, both excellent tools otherwise, but no luck so far.

**EDIT**: Philipp's answer reminded me that portability between platforms cannot be taken for granted. I'm running Linux, but I'd be most interested in fully portable solutions.

### MWE

`preamble.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
```

`main.tex`:

```
\begin{document}
  \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use a Makefile?

Comment: @YossiFarjoun:  
Does `make` know, out of the box, how to track dependencies or how to build LaTeX custom format files?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See my solution using `latexmk` at [Latexmk can't see a dependency on a .fmt format file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37496/latexmk-cant-see-a-dependency-on-a-fmt-format-file/37730#37730). It now tracks changes in the files used to make the format file.

Answer (score 11):

The following make-based approach provides the automatic re-generation of the precompiled preamble if any of its dependents (transitive closure) have changed.

It is based on `-recorder` option of `pdflatex` that, when compiling a file generates a list of all INPUT and OUTPUT files that had been accessed during the process. This list is then transformed by some `sed` script to extract a list of make-compatible dependencies. Using this list, `make` automatically rebuild the preamble if one of its input files have changed.

**Minimal Working Example**

First, the source files needed to test the approach (MWE)

`preamble.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\input{figure}
```

Note that, besides some packages, `preamble.tex` also `\input`'s a local file `figure.tex`:

```
\newcommand{\myfig}{%
\tikz \draw[thick,rounded corners=8pt] 
(0,0) -- (0,2) -- (1,3.25) -- (2,2) -- (2,0) -- (0,2) -- (2,2) -- (0,0) -- (2,0);
}
```

In the example this serves a local dependency for the precompiled preamble. Hence, editing `figure.tex` or a simple `touch figure.tex` should cause the precompiled preamble to be re-generated.

Finally, we have our `main.tex`

```
\begin{document}
  \myfig
  \lipsum
\end{document}
```

So here comes the `Makefile` that puts it all together. Just do a `make` and it will generate the precompiled preamble `main.fmt` and then `main.pdf`. Subsequent changes to `main.tex` will not trigger a regeneration of `main.fmt`. If, however, you touch `preamble.tex` or `figure.tex`, this will be detected and `main.fmt` will be re-generated:

```
#####################################################################
#
# Generate depencendcies for precompiled preamble 
#
#####################################################################

# standard options passed to sed: include only lines beginning with INPUT, 
# remove the INPUT as well as trailing ./ from paths
CREATE_DEPS_OPTIONS = -e '/^INPUT /!d' -e 's/^INPUT //' -e 's/^\.//'  

# in order to not check large parts of the local/global texmf-tree we exclude all paths that start with: 
# / or texmf/ 
DEPS_EXCLUDE ?= ^/ ^texmf/ 
CREATE_DEPS_OPTIONS += $(foreach d,$(DEPS_EXCLUDE), -e '/$(subst /,\/,$(d))/d')


# This includes the extracted deps
MAIN_DEPS= $(shell touch main.fls ; \
                            cat main.fls | \
                            sed $(CREATE_DEPS_OPTIONS) | \
                            sort -u | \
                            xargs)

all: main.pdf

main.fmt : $(MAIN_DEPS)
    @echo "****************************************"
    @echo $? changed, hence recompiling precompiled preamble 
    @echo "****************************************"
    @pdflatex -recorder -ini -jobname=main "&pdflatex preamble.tex\dump"

main.pdf : main.fmt main.tex
    @pdflatex -fmt ./main main

clean :
    @rm *.log *.aux *.pdf *.fmt *.fls
```

**Implementation Details**

The command

```
pdflatex -recorder -ini -jobname=main "&pdflatex preamble.tex\dump"
```

builds the precompiled preamble `main.fmt` with the `-recorder` option. With this option, `pdflatex` generates a list of input and output files `main.fls` it accessed during the run that looks as follows:

```
PWD /Users/lohmann/projects/stackexchange/precompiled
INPUT /opt/local/etc/texmf/texmf.cnf
INPUT /opt/local/var/db/texmf/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt
INPUT preamble.tex
OUTPUT main.log
INPUT /opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
INPUT /opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
INPUT /opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
INPUT /opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
INPUT /opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty
INPUT /opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty
... <lots of more data>
INPUT figure.tex
INPUT figure.tex
OUTPUT main.fmt
```

In the definition of the `MAIN_DEPS` variable, the `INPUT` lines from this list are extracted (via `sed` and `xargs`) into a sequence of file names that can be used as make dependencies. With `DEPS_EXCLUDE` one can pass regular expressions of patterns that should be ignored; in the example I use this to  ignore dependencies from the global texmf tree to speed up the deduction process within make. If you really want *all* dependencies to be checked every time, just set it to an empty string.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. This is indeed a nice demonstration of how to use the `-recorder` option of `pdflatex` to collect and use dependencies. I'm accepting John's answer because it is the more portable solution.

Comment: Interesting script. If I understand it correctly for every document I need to do this, I should have a directory 'mydocument' which contains the main file, the preamble and the makefile.  Is it also possible to modifiy it such that I don't need to copy the makefile everytime and that it works not only with documents called main?

Comment: @Julia: Yes, for comprehensibility, the makefile works for a single document only that here is called `main.tex`. You can easily adapt it by searching and replacing all occurrences of `main` with `mydocumentname`. It would also be possible to generalize it that it works for arbitrary document names, which would also make (sic!) it possible to manage more than one document inside the same directory.

Answer (score 4):

As per @Yossi's suggestion, you could use `make` with rules similar to:

```
main.pdf: main.fmt main.tex <other dependencies>
        pdflatex -fmt main main

main.fmt: preamble.tex <other dependencies>
        pdflatex -ini -jobname=main "&pdflatex preamble.tex\dump"
```

Of course, you can replace the command `pdflatex -fmt main main` to generate the document with some other command that does the job better, for example `latexmk` to be sure that references are resolved.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using MS Windows then a little program called [LaTeX Daemon](http://william.famille-blum.org/software/latexdaemon/index.html) might be interesting for you.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm on Ubuntu, and the code of the LaTeX daemon is not portable. How does the functionality of the LaTeX daemon compare with `latexmk -pvc`?

Comment: @user946850: I'm sorry, but I'm not familiar with `latexmk` (something I will have to change in the future).

Answer (score 2):

[WhizzyTeX](http://cristal.inria.fr/whizzytex/) (for Emacs) does this.  Normally it is used to only compile a portion of the file, but it can be made to run the entire file as well.  It actually saves a format file at the start of each "slice" (portion of the code WhizzyTex is compiling e.g. section, subsection, slide).

WhizzyTeX is meant as sort of a live-update, which might be what you're going for.  This may not be a solution for you (e.g. if you don't use Emacs), but it might give you some ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution in bash.
Not portable, but easily adaptable.

```
#!/bin/bash

####################
# CONFIGURATION
#
PREAMBLE="preamble.tex"
MAIN="./main.tex"

####################
# JOB
#
JOBNAME=$(basename ${MAIN%.*})
FMT="$(dirname "$PREAMBLE")/$JOBNAME.fmt"

COMPILE=0
if test "$FMT" -ot "$PREAMBLE"; then
    # If the preamble file has been changed
    COMPILE=1
else
    # If one of the file called by input or include in
    # the preamble file has been changed
    for input in $(grep -oE "\\\\(input|include){.+}" "$PREAMBLE"); do
        file=$(dirname "$PREAMBLE")/${input:$(expr index "$input" "{"):-1}.tex
        if test -f "$file"; then
            if test "$FMT" -ot "$file"; then
                COMPILE=1
                break
            fi
        else
            echo "Error: file '$file' (called in '$PREAMBLE') is not reachable." >&2
            exit 1
        fi
    done
fi

# Changing working directory
ORIGDIR=$PWD
cd $(dirname "$PREAMBLE")

# If some file was modified since the last compilation, we
# have to recreate the precompiled preamble
if [ $COMPILE -gt 0 ]; then
    pdflatex -ini -jobname=$JOBNAME "&pdflatex $(basename $PREAMBLE)\dump"
fi

# Changing working directory
cd $(dirname "$MAIN")

# Each time, we run the command on the main .tex file
pdflatex -fmt $(dirname "$PREAMBLE")/$JOBNAME $JOBNAME

# Returning back
cd $ORIGDIR
```