# Can't get real currfile if used in precompiled .fmt file

Tags: format-files, currfile

### Background:

I am not sure if this is a bug with [the `currfile` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/currfile), or if I not properly using the package, or perhaps an issue with using  `.fmt` files. BTW, this is my first attempt at using `.fmt` files.

Since I use the same preamble in all my documents I am trying to speed up compilation by generating a `.fmt` file as per the referenced questions below, but am having trouble with some of the things that are performed `\AtBeginDocument`.  The example below test to see that the value of the token `\MyToken` is set to the portion of the file name between the two dashes.

### Problem:

Using the precompiled `.fmt` file I get:

[image]

Note that the value of `\currfilename` is the file name of the preamble file, which is not what I want (Perhaps some `\expandafter` magic can help).

However, if I make one complete .tex file with the two given below (and remove the `%& MyPreamble`), the output you get is the desired behavior. The value of `\currfilename` is the name of the file.

[image]

### Partial Solution

- One partial solution is to use `\jobname` (as per the commented line in the preamble). Then this produces identical results in both cases. But, I can't use that in my real application as I change `\jobname` in order to generate multiple versions from the same source document.

### References:

- [Custom format file: How to automate the generation of the "precompiled preamble" whenever one of the files that are used there are changed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49388/custom-format-file-how-to-automate-the-generation-of-the-precompiled-preamble)
- [ultrafast pdflatex with precompiling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79493/ultrafast-pdflatex-with-precompiling)

### Notes:

- The actual files names here matter.
- To generate the `MyPreamble.fmt`, I use:

  ```
  pdflatex -ini -jobname=MyPreamble "&pdflatex MyPreamble.tex\dump"
  ```

### Code: `MyPreamble.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[realmainfile]{currfile}% 

\newtoks{\MyToken}
\MyToken={oo}% set default value
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \par\noindent\textcolor{blue}{Debug: currfilename = "\currfilename"}\par%
    % These two (StrBefore and StrBetween) statements do not work,
    % if this is used via .fmt file.
    \StrBefore{\currfilename}{.}[\CurrentFileName]% 
    \StrBetween[1,2]{\CurrentFileName}{-}{-}[\ExtractedValue]%
    %
    %\StrBetween[1,2]{\jobname}{-}{-}[\ExtractedValue]% this works
    \IfStrEq*{\ExtractedValue}{\the\MyToken}{}{%
        \par\noindent\textcolor{red}{Error: MyToken (middle) was "\the\MyToken", 
                but was expected to be "\ExtractedValue".}\par%
    }%
}
%% ----- preamble ends here
```

### Code: `foo-x-bar.tex`:

```
%& MyPreamble

% This file need to be named in three parts separated by two dashes.
% This need to be set to be the value in between the two dashes. So,
% if this file is named "foo-x-bar.tex", then this needs to be "x"
\MyToken={x}%

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `\getmainfile` and `\themainfile`, the correct file name is used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[realmainfile]{currfile}% 

\newtoks{\MyToken}
\MyToken={oo}% set default value
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \getmainfile
    \par\noindent\textcolor{blue}{Debug: themainfile = "\themainfile"}\par%
    % These two (StrBefore and StrBetween) statements do not work,
    % if this is used via .fmt file.
    \StrBefore{\themainfile}{.}[\CurrentFileName]% 
    \StrBetween[1,2]{\CurrentFileName}{-}{-}[\ExtractedValue]%
    %
    %\StrBetween[1,2]{\jobname}{-}{-}[\ExtractedValue]% this works
    \IfStrEq*{\ExtractedValue}{\the\MyToken}{}{%
        \par\noindent\textcolor{red}{Error: MyToken (middle) was "\the\MyToken",
                but was expected to be "\ExtractedValue".}\par%
    }%
}
%% ----- preamble ends here
```

With

```
pdflatex -recorder foo-x-bar
```

I get at the first run

[image]

Answer (score 3):

When compiling the document file, TeX does not use `\input` to load it, hence there's nothing for `currfile` to hook onto, hence why `\currfile` is not correct. You can work around this by compiling the document file instead with the command line

```
pdflatex -recorder -fmt MyPreamble '\input{foo-x-bar.tex}'
```

(Remember when loading the `currfile` package with the `realmainfile` option, you should compile with the `-recorder` option and compile twice.)

Comment: Thanks for this solution. This would have required me to change the compile command for each file, so have accepted the other answer.  I was about to switch back to using `\jobname` and adapt your solution to provide the fix for the case where I could not use `jobanme`, before egreg came to the rescue.

Comment: @PeterGrill: no problem. I too played with `\themainfile` (and I noticed you were using the `realmainfile` option to `currfile` but not using `\getmainfile` etc) but didn't get a solution as good as egreg's!