# Tool to handle "precompiling the preamble" automatically

Tags: automation, mac, preamble, format-files

On Windows there is a nice little tool called [latexdaemon](http://william.famille-blum.org/software/latexdaemon/index.html) that can handle "precompiling the preamble" (and thus speeding up compilation) automatically.  It doesn't require any additional setup: one can simply run `latexdaemon --ini=pdflatex mytexfile.tex`, and from there on it'll recompile the tex file each time it changes with [the custom format file optimization](http://magic.aladdin.cs.cmu.edu/2007/11/02/precompiled-preamble-for-latex/) (which I don't completely understand).  It also provides a console where one can force recompilation manually, or force full recompilation (without the custom format file).

I am looking for similar tools that run on OS X.

On this site I have found several [questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49388/custom-format-file-how-to-automate-the-generation-of-the-precompiled-preamble) about precompiling the preamble, but none of them automate the process: they all require splitting the preamble into a separate file manually.  I am looking for a tool that will spare me this trouble, and will let me start working on a new tex file with a single command, without the necessity to manually create multiple files and set up things *each time*.

**Update:** I tried to figure out how latexdaemon works, and the relevant bit for generating the format file is [here](http://code.google.com/p/latexdaemon/source/browse/latexdaemon/main.cpp#2084).  Looking at that code makes it clear that it's way above my level of (very basic) LaTeX knowledge though.

I think the main question which I haven't been able to solve on my own was how to generate and use a format file without splitting off the preamble into a separate file.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [Custom format file: How to automate the generation of the “precompiled preamble” whenever one of the files that are used there are changed](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49388/custom-format-file-how-to-automate-the-generation-of-the-precompiled-preamble).

Comment: Let us know if this is indeed a duplicate of the question I linked to above, and if not, please edit your question to include why it is not a duplicate.

Comment: @PeterGrill : The difference is here : "They all require splitting the preamble into a separate file."

However, I think it's a wrong cause of concern. You'll most likely be using that preamble many times, or with slight modifications, and splitting the static reusable content (most of the preamble) from the dynamic content (the rest of the preamble + the document) makes this reuse easier.

Comment: @T.Verron: Good point.

Comment: `mylatex` and its more recent update mylatexformat don't require the preamble to be in a separate file.

Comment: @Peter It's what T. Verron said, I don't want to split off the preamble into another file manually.  It was very convenient to use latexdaemon, which suported this, on Windows, and now I miss it a lot.

Comment: @T.Verron I agree that it certainly becomes necessary to split it when working on a very large document, such as a thesis.  But I often work with small, few page documents.  When worked on Windows and I could use latexdaemon, it was extremely convenient and quick to start a new document.  I'd simply like to have the same convenience on OS X: start a new document that I can share or open someone else document with a single command and be able to have very fast compilation (which gave me semi-real time preview--impossible without the speedup).

Answer (score 6):

If using the original mylatex then a command line such as

```
 pdflatex -ini &pdflatex mylatex.ltx tst.tex
```

should make a format that loads the preamble from `tst.tex`. Depending on your command line shell you may need to quote the `&` as `\&`.

Comment: Putting the `"&pdflatex"` bit in quotes also works, and should work on Windows as well.