# Need commands for creating manual "pre-compile" of preamble in Windows, perhaps by pressing a button

Tags: compiling, texworks, preamble, format-files

I would like to manually create a separate file with preamble "pre-compiled". I found a very simple example at:

[ultrafast pdflatex with precompiling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79493/ultrafast-pdflatex-with-precompiling)

where Jonas Stein describes their example:

> ```
> book.tex
> %&preamble
> \begin{document}
> Hi
> \end{document}
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> preamble.tex
> \documentclass{article}
> ```

They then proceed to instruct what to write at bash console, but I think that means they are on an OS other than Windows. Jonas suggests:

```
$ pdflatex -ini -jobname="preamble" "&pdflatex preamble.tex\dump  
$ latexmk -pdf -pvc -e '$latex=q/latex %O -shell-escape %S/' book.tex
```

Here are some other relevant articles, some with apparently other versions of the command:

- [Custom format file: How to automate the generation of the "precompiled preamble" whenever one of the files that are used there are changed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49388/custom-format-file-how-to-automate-the-generation-of-the-precompiled-preamble)
  `pdflatex -ini -jobname=main "&pdflatex preamble.tex\dump"`
- [Tool to handle "precompiling the preamble" automatically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85848/tool-to-handle-precompiling-the-preamble-automatically)
  `pdflatex -ini &pdflatex mylatex.ltx tst.tex`
- [Precompiled preamble with TikZ/Externalize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16734/precompiled-preamble-with-tikz-externalize)
  `pdflatex -ini -job-name="main" "&pdflatex fmt.tex\dump"`
- http://magic.aladdin.cs.cmu.edu/2007/11/02/precompiled-preamble-for-latex/
  `latex -ini -job-name="main" "&latex preamble.tex\dump"`
- [ultrafast pdflatex with precompiling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79493/ultrafast-pdflatex-with-precompiling)
- [Speeding up LaTeX compilation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8791/speeding-up-latex-compilation)

I don't know if the location should be pertinent, they are in:

```
C:\Users\aUserName\Documents\MikTexDocs
```

---

EDIT:
Here is what I understand so far:

For the simple files suggested by Jonas, I use the command:

```
pdflatex -ini -jobname="book" "&pdflatex preamble.tex\dump
```

How I understand this is, in command prompt, pdflatex takes option `-ini`, I'm just going to toss words in, not sure how they go (from http://ccrma.stanford.edu/planetccrma/man/man1/tex.1.html), executable, precompile macros into an fmt file. So the command above takes macros in `preamble.tex` and dumps them precompiled into a new file `book.fmt`. Now that we have a format file, we want to apply it to the `book.tex` file. So the following command has "worked":

```
pdflatex -fmt book book
```

As I understand it, this command applies the `book.fmt` file to the `book.tex` file. The PDF will now reflect a recent typesetting.

Now, I thought I would be able to get this all to work with the typeset GUI in TeXworks, so that pressing typeset would result in faster typesetting than before. But so far, typesetting with the "external" preamble only works from command line. Am I headed nowhere I intended?

Also, I thought the "preamble" `%&book` would make the typesetting action would pull the preamble from the fmt file and allow the typeset to be successful.

Comment: What a typeset button? In other words: Which TeX editor do you use? Potential answers depend on this.

Comment: The TeX editor is MiKTeX 2.9. I thought the term typeset was somewhat general? And just to be sure, I mean button in the GUI sense, not the keyboard sense. But I usually type command+T to typeset, rather than clicking on typeset button.

Comment: No, MiKTeX is your TeX distribution, but it contains TeXworks as editor. And, yes, “Ctrl +T” (not command, that’s on Mac kbd.) is there used as keystroke for, as it is called, typesetting – so very, very probably you use this. For your wish of “button use” adapt [Configuring TeXworks processing tools](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85417/configuring-texworks-processing-tools). You have to create a new prosessing tool, in your case with one executable, already used in another tool, and several command line options.