# Preamble file in Tex Text

Tags: mactex, inkscape

I'm using Tex Text in Inkscape (0.91) on a Mac (OS Sierra) (with MacTex) and it's basically functional, but I can't seem to use a preamble file (.ini). I've tried having a very simple preamble file of `\usepackage{amsmath}` but that results in the following error output:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "textext.py", line 210, in cb_ok
    self.callback(self.text, self.preamble_file, self.scale_factor)
  File "textext.py", line 369, in <lambda>
    converter_cls, old_node))
  File "textext.py", line 387, in do_convert
    new_node = converter.convert(text, preamble_file, scale_factor)
  File "textext.py", line 875, in convert
    return PdfConverterBase.convert(self, *a, **kw)
  File "textext.py", line 750, in convert
    self.tex_to_pdf(latex_text, preamble_file)
  File "textext.py", line 727, in tex_to_pdf
    exec_command(['/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex', self.tmp('tex')] + latexOpts)
  File "textext.py", line 596, in exec_command
    % (' '.join(cmd), p.returncode, out + err))
RuntimeError: Command /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex /var/folders/cr/6n190wb14px1csr_s38dgp_m0000gp/T/tmpcoRZLT/tmp.tex -interaction=nonstopmode -halt-on-error failed (code 1): This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(/var/folders/cr/6n190wb14px1csr_s38dgp_m0000gp/T/tmpcoRZLT/tmp.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31>
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
! Undefined control sequence.
l.3         {\rtf
                 1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1504
? 
! Emergency stop.
l.3         {\rtf
                 1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1504
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on tmp.log.
```

Any ideas on what could be causing this error?

Comment: What is on line three of this file? Have you defined or neglected to define a command called `\rtf`? (Note that, for *TeX-related problems, it is usually very important to post a stripped down and minimal `.tex` file that produces the error you are trying to fix.  This is sometimes called a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528).

Comment: The preamble file literally contains only the one line: `\usepackage{ams math}`, so there is no line three in this file.

Comment: Well, `\usepackage{ams math}` (note the space) should fail (I'm surprised to learn it does not; but use `\usepackage{amsmath}` in the future), but not with the error you are describing. But are you trying to compile your preamble? Because, if not, even the most minimal (but complete) **LaTeX** file will have at least three lines....

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo on my part (stupid new computer auto-corrects everything I type). The preamble file I'm describing only contains `\usepackage{amsmath}`.  I believe TexText tries to compile the preamble (which is a .ini, not .tex file) in order to generate Latex objects in Inkscape. Does the "most minimal (but complete)...three lines" rule apply to .ini preamble files as well?

Comment: I'm not sure, to be honest. I don't use Inkscape very much and have never used TexText. By compile, do you mean it is trying to create a format file (see, e.g., [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49388/8528))? In a normal LaTeX document, you can't compile just the preamble in the normal sense of the word. As an aside: I is there a group dedicated to Inkscape somewhere? You might find more people there who have good working knowledge of what Inkscape is up to....

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you a definite answer and would rather only write a comment, but TeX.SE won't let me.

As a diagnostic step, I would try to get hold of the temporary TeX file that textext writes to file and compile it manually. You might edit your `textext.py` file as follows:

```
  
    # comment out the command that calls LaTeX  
    # exec_command(['/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex', self.tmp('tex')] + latexOpts)
    print 'options', latexOpts
    print 'temp file', self.tmp('tex')
    # quit after printing diagnostic output
    raise SystemExit
```

that should give you the location of the temp file. Open it in your TeX editor, inspect, and try to compile. Then you can find out whether textext writes a broken file or uses broken options, or whether there is something else wrong with your setup.

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution for version 1.4:
In the Inkscape extensions folder, which can be found at 'C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\inkscape\extensions\textext' for Windows, edit the base.py file as follows:

The class TexToPdfConverter at Line 747 starts with:

```
**YOUR DOCUMENT CLASS and PREAMBLE GOES HERE**
DOCUMENT_TEMPLATE = r"""
\documentclass{article}
%s
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
%s
\end{document}
"""
```

Then just use the TexText extension as usual.