# Using LaTeXmk with mylatexformat

Tags: latexmk

I looked at many posts about the use of `latexmk`, but wasn't able to find what to write in order to satisfy my requirements. Yet I'm sure it is possible, but my skills in Perl amounts to about nothing.

What I would like to do with a file, say `mymainfile.tex`:

1. make a format file including the static part of the preamble, named  `mymainfile-xelatex.fmt` if I use `xelatex`, and store it in the `fmt/ subdirectory` of the directory that contains `mymainfile.tex` (I can do that just with `mylatexformat`)
2. regenerate the format if the (static part of the) preamble has changed (loading new packages, defining new commands or modifying existing commands).
3. Compiling `mymainfile.tex` with the customised format file.

The difficulty for me is point 2), and possibly point 1) — that is, not having to write a first macro to make the format, and the launching `latexmk`, but preferably that everything be done from `latexmk`.

Moreover I prefer not to write the static part of the preamble in a separate file, but keep it in mymainfile.tex as usual, and use the \endofdump command from the mylatexformat package

I use MiKTeX 2.9 on WinEdt 7.

Comment: Does the answer there (by the author of latexmk) help you? There's also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79493/ultrafast-pdflatex-with-precompiling.

Comment: Well, not exactly. It is one of the answers I had read. I must say I didn't understand all the code given there, but I understood one thing: it supposes the static part of the preamble to be written in a separate file. What I would like to be able to do is to have it in the main document as usual, only delimited by the command \endofdump (from mylatexformat package) or \begin{document} if there is no dynamic part of the preamble.  I guessed one can take advantage of LaTeXmk's ability to detect changes in the preamble to let it redo the customised format.

Comment: Hi @bernard. Are there any news here?

Comment: @Johannes_B: Unfortunately no. I confess I had so many things to do that I had forgotten this problem. Thanks for reminding me; as soon as I have some time, I'll look after it.

Comment: Just doing a bit of cleaning around, no need to hurry ;-)

Comment: 1) mylatexformat's job is to not need moving the preamble to a separate file.
2) The format name (specified with -jobname) must be mymainfile, not mymainfile-sth, to avoid certain issues with `\jobname` having the wrong value in the static preamble. (Maybe the format name can be renamed after the build, haven't tried.)

Comment: But if you accept having a separate file and give up on mylatexformat, you can use this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37730/1340
Otherwise, it's much harder to only build B only when some lines of A change.