# Why latexmk does ignore my (index) custom dependency and subroutine?

Tags: indexing, latexmk

Consider the following `latexmkrc` configuration file (say `latexmkrc.tex`) containing a custom dependency which is supposed to run the `texindy` subroutine whenever a `.ind` file is out-of-date  with respect to the corresponding source file:

```perl
# $makeindex = 'texindy'; #$

add_cus_dep('idx', 'ind', 0, 'texindy');
sub texindy{
    system("texindy \"$_[0].idx\""); #$
}

$pdf_mode = 1; #$
```

Now, consider a `.tex` file (say `test.tex`) processed with:

```bash
latexmk -g -norc -r latexmkrc.tex test
```

where:

- `-g` option to force `latexmk` to process the document fully (just for the example),
- `-norc` option just to be sure no other `latexmk` configuration file than `latexmkrc.tex` is taken in account.

Then, the following happens:

1. Running `pdflatex  -recorder  "test.tex"`.
2. Running `makeindex  -o "test.ind" "test.idx"`.
3. Running `pdflatex  -recorder  "test.tex"`.

The trouble is with step #2, `latexmk` creating a new rule:

```bash
=== Creating rule for 'cusdep idx ind test'
Latexmk: applying rule 'makeindex test.idx'...
Rule 'makeindex test.idx': File changes, etc:
   Non-existent destination files:
      'test.ind'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'makeindex test.idx'
------------
------------
Running 'makeindex  -o "test.ind" "test.idx"'
```

ignoring the custom dependency and subroutine in `latexmkrc.tex` that is supposed to lead to: `texindy  -o "test.ind" "test.idx"` instead.

As a workaround, one could comment out the line

```perl
# $makeindex = 'texindy'; #$
```

in `latexmkrc.tex` but I'm still puzzled: why `latexmk` does ignore my (index) custom dependency and subroutine?

**Minimal complete example:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\makeindex

\begin{filecontents*}{latexmkrc}
# $makeindex = 'texindy'; #$

add_cus_dep('idx', 'ind', 0, 'texindy');
sub texindy{
    system("texindy \"$_[0].idx\""); #$
}

$pdf_mode = 1; #$
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
Foo\index{Foo}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you mean "uncomment" the line? I think the reason is that `latexmk` already has a rule for converting `.idx` files to `.ind`, so it doesn't consider the "new" rule. (See this answer to a similar problem I had a few years ago, but where only the input extension was the same: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37730/9517 )

Comment: @T.Verron Doesn't "comment out" means "uncomment": sorry if I am wrong (my globbish needs to be polished :) I am suspecting what you guess but, even if the `latexmk`'s rule is first deleted by `remove_cus_dep('idx', 'ind');`, the trouble still occurs.

Comment: For me "comment out" means "comment instead of deleting", but I don't know. As for `remove_cus_dep`, I don't think built-in rules are `cus_dep`s.

Comment: @T.Verron Outch! The Perl code in the answer to your question is beyond my competence :)

Comment: The point was just the initial remark. `;)` This answer evolved a lot due to follow-up questions by other commenters, the version of that code in my `.latexmkrc` is just 3 lines long.

Comment: @T.Verron What are these 3 lines?

Comment: More or less the same I had written in the question. My problem was really only with the extensions. Anyway, your problem is much easier to solve, since `latexmk` provides this `makeindex` variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got two rules for making an `.ind` file from an `.idx` file: the built-in makeindex rule and your custom dependency.  `Latexmk` has to choose which.  The way it's programmed, it finds the built-in rule first, so that's what get used.

As you've noticed, to use `texindy` you need to redefine `$makeindex`, either by

```
$makeindex = 'texindy';
```

or (slightly better) by

```
$makeindex = 'texindy %O -o %D %S';
```

Comment: slightly off-topic: is there a way to customize `$makeindex` without a latexmkrc file, from command line only ?

Comment: See the documentation about option `-e`, which executes Perl initialization code.  You can use it to make an assignment to `$makeindex`.

Comment: ok, I had not read enough. Do you think ``-e "\$makeindex=q/makeindex -s foo.ist %O -o %D %S/"`` has any chance to work cross-platform ? it works on my mac os x (I actually use `\$$makeindex` because this is in a Makefile variable), but I have no idea about Windows. (I know I am getting even more off-topic, and don't feel in any way like you need to answer). Not knowing for sure I think I will go for the `latexmkrc` way nevertheless (hoping I don't have to worry about the endline character of my single line).

Comment: I am pretty sure it won't work cross platform.  In Windows, $ is not a special character (IIRC), so it won't need to be escaped.  But % is, and it is escaped by doubling it.  Don't forget `latexmk`'s `-r` option that reads a named initialization file.