# Adding a new engine in TeXShop

Tags: mac, editors, texshop, xindy, scripts

I would like to add a new engine in TeXShop which is able to perform the `xindy` command in the following way:

```
texindy -g meindok.idx
```

I do not want to call the command every time from the command line, instead the dropdown menu integrated in TeXShop is quite comfortable. Unfortunately, I have no idea where the current engines shown in TeXShop are saved. There must have been a change since 2015 because all the posts which I found say that you have to create an engine in `~/Library/TeXShop/Engines` but that path does not exist any more.

Comment: There has been no change in the location of the TeXShop engines.  Are you sure you're looking in `~/Library/TeXShop`?  Use the Go menu from the Finder or the terminal to get there.

Comment: Alternatively you could add a custom `.latexmkrc` file to allow the `latexmk` engines to run `texindy` instead of `makeindex`. See [Why latexmk does ignore my (index) custom dependency and subroutine?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/335170/2693) for details.  For how to make an engine in TeXShop see [Do we need to manually invoke pythontex? TeXShop Engine: PythonTeX with XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/284849/2693).

Comment: One other alternative would be to use `arara`, in which case you would use the `arara` engine, but need to write your own `texindy` rule for `arara`.  See [Using arara with texcount](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/276866/2693) for an example.

Comment: Thanks so far. I found the folder with the engines but I still have no idea how to make such an engine... Especially I do not know how to set a path name so that the command works, no matter which file is opened in TeXShop.

Comment: One other useful tidbit: to get to `~/Library` in MacOS in Finder, click the `Go` menu and then hold down the `option` key.  "Library" will magically appear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Making a `texindy` Engine

Here's what your `texindy.engine` should look like.

```bsh
#! /bin/bash
PATH=/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/bin:${PATH}
bfname=${1%\.*}
texindy -g "$bfname".idx
```

Make sure you set the executable bit on the file. In the Terminal type:

```bsh
chmod +x ~/Library/TeXShop/Engines/texindy.engine
```

### Making a `texindy` rule for `arara`

An alternative way to do this (although the two approaches are not incompatible) is to make an `arara` rule to run `texindy`.  We can do this modelled after the `makeindex` rule given in the `arara` manual.

First, move the `arara.engine` from the `Inactive` folder to the `Engines` folder in `~/Library/TeXShop` if you haven't already.

Then, you need to make a local configuration file for `arara` to tell it where to find your custom rules.  This should be saved as `~/araraconfig.yaml` (i.e., in your home folder.)

Make a directory for your local rules somewhere in your home folder.  For example if you make a folder `arara` in your home folder you would put the following, but the folder can be anywhere (for example, mine is in my Dropbox folder so that all my Macs can find it.) You just need to specify the place in this file.

```yaml
!config
paths:
- /Users/andy/arara
```

Now in the `arara` folder you've created, we can add the following rule called `texindy.yaml`

```yaml
!config
identifier: texindy
name: texindy
command: texindy @{style} "@{ getBasename(file) }.idx"
arguments:
- identifier: german
flag: <arara> @{ isTrue( parameters.german, "-g" ) }
```

This is an `arara` rule that will allow you to call `texindy` with `arara`. I've set up the rule to be able to pass the `-g` option; if you need other options you will need to add them similarly to the rule.

Now in your source document you can put the following, which should do all the necessary runs for you automatically. (You may need to adjust the order.)

```
%!TEX TS-program = arara
% arara: pdflatex 
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: texindy: { style: german }
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{book}
...
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Another and hopefully the last question so far: How to make an engine that executes the following other engines in that order: LaTeX, BibTeX, texindy, LaTeX, LaTeX

Comment: @Andy As I mentioned in the the other comment, it would probably be best to use `latexmk` for this. It is very smart and all you would need would be to create a `latexmkrc` file which tells it to use `texindy` instead of `makeindex` Or `arara` could do this too.  The links I gave should give you an idea how to proceed.

Comment: @Andy I've added an `arara` solution.

Comment: Thanks again. It works perfect and does exactly what it has to do

Answer (score 2):

Unless you always want to use `xindy -g` you may not need to do much to use pdflatexmk by creating a `platexmkrc` file that contains the line

```perl
$makeindex = "texindy -g %O -o %D %S";
```

(add a blank line after this) and place it in the same directory as the project that needs it. PS: the file has a leading 'p' in its name because it's meant to be used for a project and will be used for all files in the same directory as the file. Then place the line

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk
```

near the top of your root `.tex` file. From then on using Typeset->Typeset (Cmd-T) will completely compile your document.

Comment: Thanks, Herb. This is indeed simple. I didn't realize `latexmk` allowed project level configuration files.

Comment: @AlanMunn : The TeXShop latexmk engines all allow for a `project` configuration file named `platexmkrc` with special configuration for all compilable files in a given folder. It turns out to be pretty useful for special cases.